# Angular dev server error Channel: Error in handleResponse UNK/SW_UNREACHABLE options getValue

Tags: javascript, angular

I have recently installed a new angular app. While executing the ng serve the application gets loaded. But after couple of seconds I am getting some weird error in console.

```
Channel: Error in handleResponse UNK/SW_UNREACHABLE options getValue
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
7commons.js:2 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
fromGeneric @ commons.js:2
fromAny @ commons.js:2
_handleResponsePromise @ commons.js:2
(anonymous) @ commons.js:2
```

Not sure why this error happens.
My package.json content as below

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.1.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
```

This is first time I am getting this error. And in internet also I am not getting any relevant information. So kindly help me out.

Comment: Do you have the evernote extension running ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the response, I have disabled that extension and it got resolved.

Comment: I thought I was going crazy. I was getting this error and wasn't even working in Angular.

Answer (score 20):

For anyone who randomly has the same issue, it's the Evernote extension. Matthieu Riegler said it as a comment, so I decided to just post it to make it clearer.

Here's a link from an Evernote forum of sorts: https://discussion.evernote.com/forums/topic/145285-console-channel-error-in-handleresponse-unksw_unreachable-error/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and once I logged in to the evernote app through the evernote clipper (in the Chrome extension in teh title bar) the error went away.